# change date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd in angular on input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using D.O.B field in register form which is a reactive form where input type of D.OB i am using is type = "date"
The format I am getting is in dd-mm-yyyy but I want the format to be yyyy-mm-dd on my html side..

is there a way to do this and if yes then how..
angular version is 12
To be specific again I want my view on client side to be of yyyy-mm-dd format not of dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Import DatePipe from '@angular/common' in the “app.module.ts” file.

```
import DatePipe from '@angular/common';

....

providers:[
 DatePipe
],
```

Import DatePipe in your components and construct

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

...
constructor(private datepipe:DatePipe){

}

ngOnInit(){
 var ddMMyyyy = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

you can refer this article to get more idea:

https://www.code-sample.com/2019/02/angular-7-date-format-datepipe-example_23.html

Comment: my question was how to show it in yyyy/MM/dd format on html side i.e on screen using input type = date

Answer (score -1):

```
const format = 'yyyy/MM/dd';
const myDate = '2021-07-27';
const locale = 'en-US';
const formattedDate = formatDate(myDate, format, locale);
```

[Link](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

Comment: my question was how to show it in yyyy/MM/dd format on html side i.e on screen using input type = date..

Comment: I have the same question @abhassrivastava